# ByRef underlined with "Expression Expected" error in VB.Net when trying to pass in a object of type List(Of clsFooDetail)

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I work with C# 99% of the time. However, I'm having to update some legacy VB.Net code and encountering an issue with VB.Net code syntax. The error that I get is "ByRef" is underlined and "Expected Expression" tag shows up when you hover over "ByRef".

The "FooDetail.Load" function is written in C# and expects a List object passed as reference. Don't have any trouble using the same function in other C# classes. Can someone indicate what is wrong with below VB.Net code.

```
Dim FooDetail As New clsFooDetail()
FooDetail.FooID = FooID
Dim lstFooDetail As New List(Of clsFooDetail)
FooDetail.Load(ConnectionString, "Stored Procedure", ByRef lstFooDetail as System.Collection.List(Of(clsFooDetail))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a variable in a method call.  Nor do you use the equivalent of "out".  And don't use "As New" when the method returns a new list.  Write it like this:

```
Dim lstFooDetail As List(Of clsFooDetail)
FooDetail.Load(ConnectionString, "Stored Procedure", lstFooDetail)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. I had tried the second line same as yours but did not realize to remove the "As New" from the first line.